# deixar primeiro item do select selecionado

Tags: html, select, vue.js

boa tarde a todos, tudo bem com vocês?
Seguinte, estou listando uns cursos com v-for e ele vai de boa, porém, option precisa ser selecionado e gostaria que o primeiro item do select já aparecesse selecionado, para indicar ao cliente melhor...ele funciona, mas tá tudo em branco...não tá errado, só tá feio, como faço para que o option apareça de primeira??
Obrigado a todos!!
Horácio

```
<select v-model="cursos" id="cursos" class="form-control" name="cursos">
  <option v-for="item in ListaDeCursos" :value="item.from">
     {{item.from}} 
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

A seção [Basic Usage > Select](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select) da documentação aborda este assunto:

> If the initial value of your v-model expression does not match any of the options, the  element will render in an “unselected” state

Tradução livre:

> Se o valor inicial da expressão no `v-model` não coincidir com nenhum dos `<option>`, o elemento `<select>` será renderizado em um estado **não selecionado**.

Para isto basta dar um valor válido ao `v-model`. Exemplo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    opcoes: ['Opção 1', 'Opção 2', 'Opção 3'],
    selecionado: 'Opção 2'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selecionado">
    <option v-for="opcao in opcoes" :value="opcao">
      {{ opcao }}
    </option>
  </select>
</app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente com o código abaixo.

A ideia é verificar se o index do item é 0. Se for, marca a option como selected.

```
<select v-model="cursos" id="cursos" class="form-control" name="cursos">
  <option v-for="(item, index) in ListaDeCursos" :value="item.from" :selected="index == 0">
     {{item.from}} 
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

No final do código onde você termina de carregar a lista, pegue o primeiro elemento da lista

```
this.cursos = array[0]
```